# How to Load AWS Config from DB instead of credential.json

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, configuration

Is there any way to load AWS keys & secret keys by getting it from DB instead of using load from json or any other method.
What i want to do is i want to store aws key, Access key and region in DB and then load the configuration by fetching from DB.

```
const path = require('path');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('...path to credential.json');
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(null);
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
module.exports = s3
```

right now this is what i use i import the key from json file.

also is it safe to commit credential.json file in private github repository?

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://dev.to/dvddpl/where-do-you-keep-credentials-for-your-lambda-functions-5dno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup the credential in DB and during project initialize fetch the AWS credentials from DB and use the filesystem to generate a JSON file and then load this JSON file into the AWS config